# compiling error when using community golang buildpack on bluemix

Tags: go, cloud-foundry, ibm-cloud

One of my bluemix application worked for weeks but it start to report parse error with `Buildpack compilation step failed` when pushing app to bluemix:

```
-----> Downloaded app package (556K)
Cloning into '/tmp/buildpacks/buildpack-go'...
Submodule 'compile-extensions' (https://github.com/cloudfoundry-incubator/compile-extensions.git) registered for path 'compile-extensions'
Cloning into 'compile-extensions'...
Submodule path 'compile-extensions': checked out 'f752ecf4b27d2f31bb082dfe7a47c76fefc769d7'
-------> Buildpack version 1.4.0
parse error: Expected separator between values at line 32, column 3
Staging failed: Buildpack compilation step failed
```

Here's my `manifest.yml` file:

```
---
applications:
- name: joystick
  memory: 128M
  path: .
  buildpack: https://github.com/cloudfoundry/buildpack-go.git
```

**Update**: I carefully read the error message and figured out it is application space problem caused by `Godeps.json` parsing error caused by code merging where one comma is missed. I can not reproduce this locally because I checked in `_workspace` directory where it never parse `Godeps.json`.

I created [issue 86](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go/issues/86) to improve this buildpack to provide more information for such kind of error message.

Comment: When was the last time you deployed your app? It looks like the buildpack recently was bumped to 1.4.0 - perhaps this buildpack causes an issue in Bluemix. Try using an older version of the buildpack when you push your app using the `-b` option

Comment: I uses buildpack 1.4.0 for a while. actually this is caused by application itself. the error message itself tells part of the information because it seems compiling error but no golang specific information provided. so I start to guess it comes from godep configuration `Godeps/Godeps.json` file because it is only place need to be parsed by buildpack. so my suggestion is improving the buildpack output message for such error path.

Comment: ok, go ahead and provide an answer to your question so it's closed out for future SO users :)

Answer (score 1):

The error message `parse error: Expected separator between values at line 32, column 3` comes from `jq` command within buildpack code, where it tries to read import path from `Godeps/Godeps.json` by assuming it's a valid JSON file. see line #64 of [`/bin/compile`](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go/blob/master/bin/compile#L64).

It will stop buildpack if the `Godeps.json` is not json.

I created [issue 86](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-go/issues/86) to improve this buildpack to provide more information for such kind of error message.

Thanks for everyone who spent time on this problem.

**Update**: issue 86 was fixed in heroku golang buildpack by adding new step to checking `Godeps.json` format.